# What's up with RF Online? Can't even register on the website

Tags: rf-online

What's up with the game? I just found the link  and wanted to try it out. However, I can't even register. It throws different (non-sense) error messages. The emails won't arrive, and once when I successfully registered it won't let me in.

Has the game been shut down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The game is no longer available in North America and Europe due to contract issues between CCR and Codemasters. It may still be available in Asia. ([Source](http://www.escapistmagazine.com/news/view/86598-RF-Online-Goes-Offline))

Comment: Note: They should *really* put some kind of NOTICE or NOTE on their website... eh

Comment: @Shiki - Yeah, that's pretty annoying. From their comments, I get the impression that Codemasters was hoping to work something out in the future, but still...